# Oracle column Alias - from keyword not found where expected

Tags: oracle10g

```
SELECT col1 'COLUMN 1'
FROM TABLENAME
```

I am getting an error 'from keyword not found where expected'

How can you give column alias in Oracle 10g some examples are appreciated

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
SELECT col1 "COLUMN 1" FROM TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 4):

Shepherdess is correct - you can't use single quotes here.

If the alias doesn't have spaces, you could just type the name without any quotes:

```
SELECT col1 column1 FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Of note, aside from containing whitespaces, a label starting with a non-alphabet character (i.e. a digit or underscore) you'll need the double quotes then too.

Comment: Also, if you are creating an alias for proper column title names, and letter casing is important, you'll need double quotes.  At least you do in Oracle SQL Developer, otherwise all titles end up in caps.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes is not allowed here .Either you have to use double quotes or not quots between column1.Careful about column1 because it doesn't supported any spaces between column1.